# Pandas dataframe merging but creating NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes with one column in each which looks like:

```py
df1                        df2
Price                     volume
 20                        200
 12                        50
 43                        10
 45                        5
```

When I try to merge the two dataframes using: new_df = pd.concat([Volume, Price], axis=1) i get

```py
    Volume      Price
3   20           NaN
4   NaN          200
5   12           NaN
6   NaN          50
7   43           NaN
```

I've tried using pd.concat / pd.merege / pd.join but can't seem to get a clean merge. whats the best way to go about fixing this?

Comment: you're not sharing the full dataframes, they each have indexes and concat is trying to match the rows by index, perhaps you can try with `ignore_index=True`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Price': [20, 12, 43, 45]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'volume': [200, 50, 10, 5]})

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

It works for me and I do not get any NaN values. Use dataframe names in pd.concat, not column names.